# File uploading using struts-layout and error ConversionException, Cannot assign value of type

Tags: jsp, struts-1, struts-layout

I have a problem when I use struts-layout for file uploading.

Here is my form-bean in struts-config.xml

```
<form-bean name="accounts$cardholderCreateForm" dynamic="true" type="org.apache.struts.validator.DynaValidatorActionForm">
    <form-property name="photoImage"                type="org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile"/>
</form-bean>
```

and in .jsp file below

```
<layout:form action="/cardholder/cardholderCreate.do" reqCode="createCardholder" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <layout:file key="accounts.cardholder.photoImage.prompt" property="photoImage" fileKey="FILE" mode="E,E,E"/>
</layout:form>
```

When I try to load this page, I get the error message.

```
class org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConversionException, Cannot assign value of type '[B' to property 'photoImage' of type 'org.apache.struts.upload.FormFile'
```

Can you give me any suggestion about this error message? and what should I do for this?